# How to POST to a PHP variable with Ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I went through countless tutorials/answers and still can't find a way to echo `var myContent` in `$htmlContent` with Ajax POST on the same page. If someone could please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

**PHP**

```
$htmlContent = $_POST['htmlContent'];
   
echo $htmlContent;
```

**Ajax**

```
function myFunction() {
  
var myContent = '<p>my content</p>';
  
  $.ajax({
   url: '',
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: "html",
   data: {htmlContent: myContent},
   success: function (results) {             
    alert("it works!");  
    }
  });
   
}
```

Comment: What is the result? Php errors? Console errors?

Comment: If the button is in a form, make it type="button"

Comment: Also you need to set `url: '',` to something useful

Comment: The alert says "it works!", also tried url: 'mypage.php' and still can't echo $htmlContent. I don't want to use a form if that's possible. As far as I can see, I don't have any errors in the Console or with PHP.

Comment: Echo where? You are not doing anything with the result. Change `alert("it works!");` to `console.log(results)`

Comment: OK thanks yes I can see <p>my content</p> being echoed in the console, but not on the page. Maybe something to do with dataType?

Comment: You of course need to assign the string to a container!!! `document.getElementById("someContainerOnPage".innerHTML=results` - it’s not magically going to show on the page on its own

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to POST and grab myContent with $htmlContent = $_POST['htmlContent'];. Is this possible with Js?

Comment: Yes, I just told you how a pointless going via the server just to pass html around

Comment: Thanks for your time on this, but I need to pass it to a PHP variable to work with a script.

Comment: This is not possible. PHP needs server ( reload ) to run and show something, AJAX targetted for the same page will not work. It can do something on server and show the result but cannot do anything on the same page before or even after reload.